# WPF C# Обращение к объекту через ссылку

Tags: c#, wpf

Пытаюсь обратиться к элементу из ссылок таким образом: [image: обращение к элементу]

В ссылках проекта он задан:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

при попытке компиляции он не находит её и почему-то лезет в bin/Debug проекта

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При обращении через полный путь всё работает корректно, но нужно взять адрес именно из ссылок. Подскажите, в чем проблема?

Comment: подскажите, пожалуйста, зачем reference на .png ? 
Не находит, потому что в свойствах файла нужно указать "Copy to Output Directory": "Copy if newer"

Comment: Reference это что? Я изначально пробовал Uri(@"date/Mob.png") , но в таком случае получал ошибку связанную с определением URI. Можете подсказать вариант для того, чтобы наложить изображение на rectangle.fill через imagebrush?

Comment: Я так понял, что это resources это свойство поля build action, которое встравает в проект сей файл

Comment: @Flutter развернул более подробно, что я хотел до вас донести. все дело в том что приложение будет определять путь к картинке отталкиваясь от своего. соответственно эта картинка должна лежать  в Debug/Bin/data. чтобы это произошло, при компиляции нужно дать понять студии, что необходимо скопировать туда этот файл. для этого в свойствах файла измените параметр на "всегда копировать" или "копировать, если нет"  - не знаю как это выглядит в руссифицированной версии

Comment: References - у вас выглядят как "Ссылки", от чего, признаюсь, у меня дергается глаз..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UriKind.Relative предполагает, что путь будет относительно рабочей папки приложения (debug в данном случае). Если хотите, чтобы изображения автоматически туда копировались, поставьте свойство Copy to output dir для каждого изображения (в окне properties).

Comment: Поставил свойство "Копировать в выходной каталог": Копировать всегда. Ошибка та же, да и самого файла в папке с exe.шником так и не видел во время компиляции.

Comment: В общем, все сводится к использованию файлов в одной папке с exe. файлом.